# QuickLookSatellite MAC OS, High CPU Use

Tags: macos, macbook, osx-mountain-lion, macbook-pro, cpu-usage

I have consistently been having a problem with my computer overheating due to the process QuickLookSatellite-general using 100+ CPU use.  (Please see images attached.)

[image]

[image]

On googling I found this process is associated with Draftsight, a CAD program.  I do not and have never had this program installed.

Restarting does not even fix this problem.  I am also worried about damaging my Macbook at such high CPU temperatures.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Troubleshooting steps:

- See if there are any relevant log messages in Console.app or `/var/log/system.log`.
- Use `qlmanage -r` to reset Quick Look client's generator cache.
- Run `sudo opensnoop -n QuickLookSatellite-general` to see if the process hangs after accessing some specific files. Or select QuickLookSatellite-general in Activity Monitor, press command-I, and see the Open Files and Ports tab.
- Temporarily delete `Movie.qlgenerator`, `Audio.qlgenerator`, or other qlgenerator bundles in `/System/Library/QuickLook`, and run `qlmanage -r`.
- Temporarily remove applications shown by `qlmanage -p | grep /Applications/`.
- Disable quicklookd with `launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.quicklook.*`. The plists are loaded again after you log out and back in.

If nothing else works, you could try [doing an upgrade install of OS X from the recovery partition](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10763).

Comment: this is awesome.  Great to know for other applications as well.  Thank you!

Comment: It looks like resetting the clients generator cache seemed to solve it, but if it acts up again I will try some of your other steps.

Comment: Just to add to this I find other programs also behaving like above.  Firefox and bitcoin client behave the same way.

Comment: This started happening when I generated documentation for a Rust project which generated lots of html files. The folder was inside iCloud drive and got picked up I think. cloudd and quicklookd both started acting up.

Answer (score 3):

What I also found helpful was to turn on QuickLook debugging so I could see exactly what files were being processed. You can do that with this in the terminal. More info in the [Mac Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/quicklook_programming_guide/articles/qldebugtest.html).

```
defaults write -g QLEnableLogging YES
```

You can also adjust the debugging level using `qlmanage -d debuglevel`. Run `qlmanage -h` for more info.

In my particular case it was QuickSilver causing the issue, which I fixed by disabling image previews using this command in the terminal. My thread on that is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/blacktree-quicksilver/LeTwnOM_i7A).

```
defaults write com.blacktree.quicksilver "QSLoadImagePreviews" NO
```

Also see this similar AskDifferent [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97297/mac-os-x-10-8-quicklook-causing-cpu-temperature-spikes/118359#118359).

Answer (score 0):

For me, deleting `~/Library/Application Support/Quick Look/cloudthumbnails.db*` seems to have done the job.

Answer (score 0):

Relaunch Finder.
In general I've found this to be the culprit as it is the main application that uses QuickLook. Occasionally it can be a recurring deeper issue that requires you to dig deeper.

Aside: If you want a quick way to quit Finder and are comfortable using Terminal (this varies for different versions of MacOS)...

`defaults write com.apple.finder QuitMenuItem -bool true; killall Finder`

Answer (score -2):

For me I ran into this issue when I raised the ulimit number to a very high number. When I changed it back to ~17,000 (from ~260,000) and rebooted, my Mac ran pretty normal again. YMMV obviously.

Comment: This answer needs more information to explain how it's related to the OPs question.