# Safari and Firefox, High CPU usage during downloads

Tags: macos, firefox, process, safari

I have found both Safari and Firefox use a very high amount of CPU during downloads (>200% CPU usage), can anyone explain as to why this happens?  It occurred both before and after a complete system reinstall.  It also uses the same amount of CPU despite download speed. I am using Mac OS 10.8.

[image]

[image]

I also had images of Firefox doing the same thing, but accidentally deleted them during the reinstall.

Comment: Uhh so it's using 260% of the CPU while downloading?  That seems impossible. :)

Comment: hence the question :) Does a higher then 100% percentage mean it is using multiple cores for that process?

Comment: I'm not an OSX user so I can't say for sure, but in the Windows world, no, the CPU Percentage is 100% max (1 busy core in a 2 core system would show 50% use for example), and I would expect the same from any modern OS -- but again I don't know for sure.  That's why I commented on it.  It seems crazy, but I have no answer. :)

Comment: I see, so it should be averaging the cores.  That it is.  I've had a problem along these lines with QuickLookSatellite as well.  http://superuser.com/questions/617658/quicklooksatellite-mac-os-high-cpu-use

Comment: Activity Monitor (or `top` or `ps`) doesn't "average the cores", so 200% means 100% for two cores.

Comment: So 400% would mean all 4 cores at 100%?  Does this seem normal then?

Comment: Are you saving to HDD or SSD? Also, noticed your download speed is ~9MB/s, nice :) Does it happen when at lower speeds?

Comment: Is this a VM? I see VMWare Fusion in the list of processes...?

Comment: SSD :) Yes its very nice haha.  And no, it is not a VM.  Although I am running VMWare Fusion to host a VM. I eventually did a fresh reinstall which seemed to "mostly" solve the problem.  Although I notice it reoccurs irregularly, but much less frequently.

Answer (score 1):

I only came across this question today and I hope this is not too late an answer, but the short answers are yes (to your first question "I have found both Safari and Firefox use a very high amount of CPU during downloads (`>200%` CPU usage), can anyone explain as to why this happens?") and yes (to your comment question "Does a higher then `100%` percentage mean it is using multiple cores for that process?").

The short explanation is that your Mac contains a multi-core processor - I'm guessing a minimum of `2` given that you are running OS X 10.8 - which supports [hyperthreading](https://www.utdallas.edu/~edsha/parallel/2010S/Intel-HyperThreads.pdf), and this means that each physical core (a physical CPU in itself) presents multiple "logical" cores to OS X which it treats as independent logical CPUs. A process can use up to 100% of each logical core, so `n` logical cores means a maximum of `n x 100%` CPU usage per process.  Hence your Activity Monitor (like Task Manager in Windows) showing CPU usage bars for each of these logical cores (as long as they are `<= 4`, according to Apple technical documentation on CPU usage) and you're getting readings like `157%` for Firefox etc. This is **not** unusual and probably **normal** if you have multiple downloads, apps, games etc. running at the same time.  But note: different app processes live in different parts of the user virtual memory space, so it is also possible to see multiple app processes which have `>100%` CPU usage at the same time, e.g. Firefox `157%` and iTunes `200%` etc.

It is **impossible** to see a `>100%` CPU usage for a process in a single-core CPU system, unless the reporting tool you are using is faulty.  Firefox probably spawns a thread for each download (if you have multiple simultaneous downloads), in addition to a number of other threads for tabs, rendering etc. and other stuff going on, and your reading of `157%` for the process clearly means some of these threads were being run on at least two different logical cores at the same time. A reading of `296%` would indicate at least three cores being used etc.  The CPU usage for a process on a multi-core processor / multi-threaded OS system is an aggregate of the CPU usages for all the threads running inside that process.

Note: on a practical level you may want to consult [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-uses-too-many-cpu-resources-how-fix) if your downloading problems are specific to Firefox or are occuring repeatedly.

You can find out information on the number of physical/logical cores in your computer by using the `sysctl` command (in the BSD API if you are interested) - if you execute the following command in your terminal app:

```
$ sysctl -e hw | grep "cpu="
```

you should see something like this (note the comments I've inserted, not part of the output)

```
hw.ncpu=4         # no. of cores available to the kernel
hw.activecpu=4    # no. of logical cores actively being used by the kernel
hw.physicalcpu=2  # no. of physical cores
hw.logicalcpu=4   # no. of logical cores
```

Comment: Hope this is not against the rules, but for a more extended discussion, inspired by this question, please [see this post](http://sandeepmurthy.is/2015/01/13/OS-X-Activity-Monitor-and-CPU-Usage/).